# NPOI GetZoom of Worksheet

Tags: c#, apache-poi, npoi

I am using NPOI library to read in an existing workbook, and create a new one.  When creating an HSSFSheet. I see that there is a method called SetZoom. What I don't see is a GetZoom method, or a Zoom property, in order to tell what that Zoom level is on the existing Worksheet. Any ideas?

Comment: If you load your existing worksheet that you know has a non-default zoom (e.g. 75%), make a change to it, save it, does the resulting file have the same zoom or does it reset it to 100%?

Comment: I haven't tried this in code, but if you open up MS Excel, set your zoom to non-standard, save the document, and close it - then - Yes - next time you open it, the zoom will be still remember your non-standard setting.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to be a satisfying answer, because I'm not sure there is one. I looked through the NPOI source code ([SetZoom() in line 1161](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/blob/master/main/HSSF/UserModel/HSSFSheet.cs)) as well as the original java source code from which is was ported ([SetZoom() in line 1083](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi/3.7/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.java)). As you can see, the `SetZoom()` method simply creates an `SCLRecord`:

```
SCLRecord sclRecord = new SCLRecord();
          sclRecord.Numerator = ((short)numerator);
          sclRecord.Denominator = ((short)denominator);
          Sheet.SetSCLRecord(sclRecord);
```

And digging further (in the original java):

```
public void setSCLRecord(SCLRecord sclRecord) {
    int oldRecordLoc = findFirstRecordLocBySid(SCLRecord.sid);
    if (oldRecordLoc == -1) {
        // Insert it after the window record
        int windowRecordLoc = findFirstRecordLocBySid(WindowTwoRecord.sid);
        _records.add(windowRecordLoc+1, sclRecord);
    } else {
        _records.set(oldRecordLoc, sclRecord);
    }
}
```

Where we can see that it saves this information into a private field of `ISheet` (`InternalSheet` in java):

```
private List<RecordBase> _records;
```

Thus, this information is not publicly accessible. If the Zoom is not set, it defaults to 100%, but I'm not aware of any way to access the Zoom of an existing sheet, as there doesn't seem to be any way to do this in NPOI short of modifying the internal source code yourself. Even so, this would only give you the zoom level that you set, as opposed to the existing one already on the worksheet.

It might be possible in EPPlus if you access the `worksheet.View.ZoomScale`, but I am currently unable to test this at the moment.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to create an override class method to set and get the zoom in NPOI? EPPlus is great for XLSX, but it doesn't handle XLS.

Comment: @DavidP The problem is that I'm not sure how you can get the zoom initially in the first place, so I don't know how you'd write such a method. I think the zoom is saved somewhere outside the Excel sheet, like as a Windows setting or something. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: I suspected that you were incorrect in thinking that it was stored in a registry key or Windows setting.  Because if you set a custom zoom on a worksheet in Excel, close the file, copy the file to a new named document, and then open up the newly named document, it still remembers the custom zoom.  But based on your input, I did find the solution. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to C. Helling, I was able to deduce that the Zoom was stored in the Window2.  It, however, is stored as integer (eg - 65 for 65%, 150 for 150%).  Setting the zoom of the new worksheet based off the zoom of the old sheet, is pretty easy:

```
destWS.SetZoom(sourceWS.Sheet.WindowTwo.NormalZoom, 100)
```

Comment: Nice! I'm glad you figured it out.